# Cocos2d-x game on Android ignores first tap

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game using Cocos2d-x 3.12.  On Android (tried devices with API version 15 and 18), it runs fine, but when it's started, or when it's sent to background then foreground, the first tap on the screen is ignored, with the following message in the log:

```
I/InputQueue-JNI(16547): Sending finished signal for input channel 'hidden nav (client)' since it is being unregistered while an input message is still in progress.
I/InputQueue-JNI(16547): Ignoring finish signal on channel that is no longer registered.
```

The taps after that work ok.

It's a problem because I expect the app to respond the first time when I interact with it.  Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this behavior was happening because the main View had the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` set on it, so the first tap brought the system navigation back.  A solution more proper to my game was to just set the `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` flag, so the system navigation is visible but dimmed.